# How to add multiple forms and 'actions' on this 'html search bar'?

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<form class="guitar" action="guitar.html">
 <form class="bass" action="bass.html">  
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
 <button> 
 type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </form>
```

My question is: I can see that, the first 'form class' works. Whenever I type 'guitar' in the search bar, it will redirect to the html page that I assigned. The problem is with any other form. Am I doing something wrong? My question would be: is there a way so that I can add multiple forms and multiple "actions" ?  for example, by writting drums, you get redirected to another page, writing bass, you get redirected to another page etc. It seems that the code I'm curently having is not working as I expected it to work. Please help me, apologize for the noobness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple forms, then they can't be nested inside each other.

If you want to have *a* form which behaves differently depending on what is typed into a text field, then have *a* form and set the `action` to the URL of a server side program which will read the submitted data and return a customised response.